# How do I assign values of for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, logic

I am trying to create an interface for users which don't know anything about programming. So I want them to add some things and than after that they can copy paste the code and it all has to work.

so I have a config object which looks like this:

```
var initSocialShare = {
  config: {
    facebook: false,
    linkedin: false,
    twitter: false,
    pocket: false,
    copy: false
  } 
}
```

And than I want to render it inside a text area like this:

```
document.querySelector('#shareButton-code').innerHTML += 
   `<script> 
       var initSocialShare = {
           config: {
             facebook: ${obj},
             linkedin: ${obj},
             twitter: ${obj},
             pocket: ${obj},
             copy: ${obj}
          }
      } 
      ${initButtons} 
      ${showOverlay} 
      ${copyText} 
      initButtons()
</script>`;
```

How can I render the results of the for loop in the script:

```
for (var key in initSocialShare.config) {
  // if (!initSocialShare.config.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

  var obj = initSocialShare.config[key];
  console.log(obj);
}
```

This is in my init method where I push the link to an array:

```
 if(initSocialShare.config.facebook){
    s.push( '"#" id="fs_facebook-btn" data-count="fb" onclick="window.open(\'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + u + "', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false\" title=\"Share on Facebook\"")
  }
```

So When the user copies the code this piece above has to work

Comment: You can do this a lot easier in in a Javacscript framework called Vue. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html for a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through substitutions in template by using `tagged template` like this.

```
document.querySelector('#shareButton-code').innerHTML +=
  foo`<script>
    var initSocialShare = {
      config: {
         facebook: ${initSocialShare},
         linkedin: ${initSocialShare},
         twitter: ${initSocialShare},
         pocket: ${initSocialShare},
         copy: ${initSocialShare}
      }
    }
  </script>`;

function foo(literals, ...substitutions) {
  let result = '';
  let i = 0;

  for (const key in initSocialShare.config) {
    result += literals[i];
    result += initSocialShare.config[key];
    i++;
  }

  result += literals[literals.length - 1];
  return result;
}
```

EDITED: (includes all the substitutions now)

```
var initSocialShare = {
  config: {
    facebook: false,
    linkedin: false,
    twitter: false,
    pocket: false,
    copy: false
  }
}

const initButtons = 'foo';
const showOverlay = 'bar';
const copyText = 'baz';

document.querySelector('#shareButton-code').innerHTML +=
  foo`<script>
    var initSocialShare = {
      config: {
         facebook: ${initSocialShare},
         linkedin: ${initSocialShare},
         twitter: ${initSocialShare},
         pocket: ${initSocialShare},
         copy: ${initSocialShare}
      }
    }
    ${initButtons}
    ${showOverlay}
    ${copyText}
    initButtons()
  </script>`;

function foo(literals, ...substitutions) {
  let result = '';
  let i = 0;

  for (const key in initSocialShare.config) {
    result += literals[i];
    result += initSocialShare.config[key];
    i++;
  }

  for (let j = i; j < substitutions.length; j++) {
    result += literals[j];
    result += substitutions[j];
  }

  result += literals[literals.length - 1];
  return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks this seems kind of a good solution but how can I implement the other functions which are now declared as variables like this `${initButtons} ${showOverlay}` and all the others below because now it renders the config and initButtons().

Comment: @Sreinieren I have included dummy substitutions for the rest. Should be complete now.

Comment: Thanks this works! Only if I fire this again the old values will not be overrided

Answer (score 0):

You may write a helper function to convert an Object to string like:

```
function makeObjString(obj) {

    let str = [];
    str.push('{');

    for(let k in obj) {
        str.push(k);
        str.push(':');
        str.push(obj[k]);
        str.push(',');
    }

    str.pop();

    str.push('}');

    return str.join('');
}
```

And then just invoke it like:

```
document.querySelector('#shareButton-code').innerHTML += 
   `<script> 
       var initSocialShare = {
           config: ${makeObjString(initSocialShare.config)}
      } 
      ${initButtons} 
      ${showOverlay} 
      ${copyText} 
      initButtons()
</script>`;
```

This is in my init method where I push the link to an array:

```
 if(initSocialShare.config.facebook){
    s.push( '"#" id="fs_facebook-btn" data-count="fb" onclick="window.open(\'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + u + "', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false\" title=\"Share on Facebook\"")
  }
```

So When the user copies the code this piece above has to work

Comment: but that object will than be rendered as string? So when the user copy paste the code part of it is not working because I wrote an `if(initSocialShare.config.facebook)`

Comment: Can you share your code where you wrote the condition `if(initSocialShare.config.facebook)`?